# Using Star printer as a reciept printer on my ios cordova application

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, printing, bluetooth

I built a pos app on the IOS platform using cordova and I am trying to  integrate support for the Star Micronics bluetooth receipt printers(esp. the SM-S220), I have been to their site and the documentation is not very good, Can i get some pointers on how to implement it.

Comment: Since that printer is MFi certified and uses legacy Bluetooth you need to use the external accessory framework. Here is the iOS SDK they provide: http://www.starmicronics.com/absolutefm/absolutefm/afmviewfaq.aspx?faqid=175. I don't know if it is even possible to use the external accessory framework in Cordova, but perhaps that will give you a pointer for further searching.  They also have an app on the store called Webprnt that might help you; your app launches that app to perform the printjng

Comment: I have been able to use the StarWebPrint app on ios to integrate but the url: localhost:8001/StarWebPRNT/SendMessage  throws a server cannot be found error